# Pandas Dataframe: Removing rows but they are still in value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have this dataframe train_info with a column artist.

I decided to remove the rows corresponding to the artists from this list:

```py
lst = ["Alekos Kontopoulos",
"James Ward"]
```

After removing them i check that there are no records of them left, e.g.

```py
train_info[train_info.artist == "James Ward"]
```

and it gives an empty dataframe

```py
artist  filename
```

Then i looked at the value_counts:

```py
train_info.artist.value_counts()
```

and they are both in there...

```py
Ohara Koson             616
Carl Larsson            577
August Macke            576
John William Godward    568
Andrea Mantegna         567
                       ... 
Vittore Carpaccio        93
Conroy Maddox            93
Gerard David             92
James Ward               81
Alekos Kontopoulos       67
```

Anyone know how this can happen?

Comment: Is possible some whitespaces like `"James Ward "` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some whitespaces, so first remove them:

```
train_info.artist = train_info.artist.str.strip()
```

And then for remove rows with values in list `lst` use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
train_info[~train_info.artist.isin(lst)]
```